How to get more questions? Migrate from other SE sites?
It seems that we got at a dead point.  There are no new questions for two days, and only 3 questions at all since the time the public beta should have started originally, with 52 questions - of those 45 not closed - asked before that.
It looks that there are enough specialists here that can answer questions with good answers, but everyone who is here seems to have asked all questions he (or she) can think of, for now.
I fear there won't come much more questions from the (active) private beta users, and we won't get out of private beta without more questions.
What could we do to get more questions? Maybe mailing to all those beta users which did not post any question yet, reminding them to do so?
At the same time, there are regularly new questions tagged [cryptography] on other stack exchange sites, many of which look like they would be on-topic here, too.

Stack Overflow (only a smaller part)
Security SE
Math SE
Theoretical CS SE (their tag is named cr.crypto-security)

Should we go and steal questions from there? 
Migrating them is not possible for now, but we could select good ones, extract their essence and repost them here.
Opinions?

I do not think it is a good idea to get content for other SE sites if those questions are on topic for their existing sites. SE is specifically set up not to allow cross-posting, and manually posting questions to multiple sites is strongly discouraged, so I don't think we should be seeking on-topic content to copy to here. (Now, if there are off-topic questions on those sites that would work here, then those are definitely questions that we would want to have migrated in their entirety.)
I think ir01 is right about the private beta: we will have to come up with more questions ourselves. I'm guilty on all SE sites of not asking enough questions, and I'm sure I'm not the only one who does that. We don't want to ask bad questions just to generate content (although it doesn't hurt to ask a question that might be off-topic, if only to give people a chance to vote it off-topic as an example for similar questions); the key to getting out of private beta and making this a sustainable site is generating a stream of quality questions and answers. 

and I'm sure I'm not the only one who does that - Yes. For now, from the 190 people which signed up for beta (and 225 which committed to do so), only 42 posted at all (questions, answers or both). And at least half of the 57 questions is from people which asked more than one, I think. (No more statistics, as this is not yet available at data.stackexchange.com.)

If each signed up user would ask at least one question, we would be good, I think.

@Nine, apparently mods can email users somehow, but I don't know if this is something they can do ... I left a message in chat to see if they have something they can suggest.

This solution is useful when private beta was ended.
Add a comment under crypto.SE on-topic questions on other SE sites like:
I suppose this is the kind of questions that would better be on crypto.stackexchange.com
Adding comment is useful because:
1) We inform other SE users about Crypto.SE so more users may contribute on crypto.SE (More users).
2) More questions by new users.
In private beta more thinking for more questions.
EDIT:
as Arsen7 said: a comment similar to: "If you want to know more about [X] aspect of your problem, you may want to ask on Crypto.SE" would be perfectly acceptable, helpful and polite.
It's better.

There was a similar question on SuperUser recently, and the overwhelming response was that it is not OK to suggest migration for on-topic questions.

Suggesting to migrate the question may be indeed rude (in case the question is on-topic), but adding a comment similar to: "If you want to know more about [X] aspect of your problem, you may want to ask on Crypto.SE" would be perfectly acceptable, helpful and polite.

Thank you Arsen7.
